# AWS - CloudFormation "Waiting for association to be applied."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

I am working on rendering optimization for our project, following this tutorial: https://ec2spotworkshops.com/rendering-with-batch/start/on-your-own.html. However, it is outdated, and I am struggling to make it work. I had to update the `stack.yaml`
by adding an `ImageId` to get it started, but now it always times out on "Waiting for association to be applied." Has anyone ever seen this issue? I tried searching the web and ChatGPT but couldn't solve it, so I am trying to ask here. Any help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

P.S. There is nothing new in the CloudWatch logs

Comment: Can you add state manager logs? Should be somewhere in the console (System Manager => State Manager => specific association => Execution history)

Comment: I set it up System Manager and tried again. Now I found the error is

resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)

resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p1

failed to run commands: exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @defaultUsernameN for suggesting to use System Manager. After setting it up I found out in the logs (which are much more helpful than CloudWatch) that the stack.yaml used wrong command for Centos based OS. After replacing `resize2fs` for `xfs_growfs` it finished without any issues.